# How to access environment specific variables from static assets in sails.js?

Tags: sails.js

I've configured my sails.js application for static assets using the static asset generator.  I have an angular application in my assets folder.  My angular app needs to know some environment specific data such as the sails api url.  In the api I can access environment specific environment with a hook like this: `sails.config.url` however in the static assets angular application I do not have access to the sails hook.  I thought maybe I'll have to register a new grunt task like grunt-replace and try to do it there, but just checking to see if there is a better way.

Comment: If you would like an additional resource, here is a chat room for sails.js, node.js, and waterline questions. They might be able to give youa quick answer.  https://gitter.im/balderdashy/sails

Comment: It would be much better to provide an answer in this Q so others can find it after a google search :)